# How to enable c99 and c11 on gcc?

Tags: compiling, gcc, c

When I compile the following code it gives compilation error that

```
 error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
 for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

and to compile your code use this option :

```
 note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
```

Now my question is this how to use the above option and enable c99 and c11?

Answer (score 6):

As conveyed in the error message, you should compile the code using `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99`. So, for example, your file is `filename.c`, then compile using:

```
gcc -std=c99 filename.c
```

which will produce a binary `a.out` if there are no more errors. If you don't want to use this option, you can declare `i` before the `for` loop as follows:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

and compile it using:

```
gcc filename.c
```